# Create format from a string

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called `data` that I have imported from an online database, along with a data dictionary.

I also have a dataframe called `dictionary` which has the formats in the follwoing format:

```
"0, Female | 1, Male"
```

Both dataframes can be generates like:

```
data <- data.frame(study_id = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004),
                   first_name = c("John", "Jane", "Jack", "Jill"),
                   last_name = c("Doe", "Smith", "Jones", "Windsor"),
                   sex = c(1, 0, 1, 0),
                   ethnicity = c(0, 1, 0, 2))
dictionary <- data.frame(field_name = c("study_id", "first_name", "last_name", "sex", "ethnicity"),
                select_choices_or_calculations = c(NA, NA, NA, "0, Female | 1, Male", "0, Hispanic or Latino | 1, NOT Hispanic or Latino | 2, Unknown / Not Reported" ))
```

Is there a way that I can apply a factor the columns `sex` and `ethnicity` with this string. Effectively, generating the following code (or doing the same thing) from the string:

```
data$sex <- factor(data$sex,levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("Female", "Male"))
```

Comment: It seems to me that you must have _two_ data frames (or their equivalent): one containing information on your participants, the other containing your formatting strings.  Please supply samples of both that are sufficient to reproduce (and then solve) your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following function should do the job:

```r
factorize <- function(data, format) {
  dat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(format, '\\s+\\|\\s+')[[1]], 
                               function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, ',\\s+'))))
  factor(dat[,2][match(data, as.numeric(dat[,1]))], dat[,2])
}
```

In your example case, we could use this as follows:

```r
data[] <- lapply(seq_along(data), function(x) {
  i <- match(names(data)[x], dictionary$field_name)
  val <- dictionary$select_choices_or_calculations[i]
  if(is.na(val)) return(data[[x]])
  factorize(data[[x]], val)
})
```

Resulting in

```
data
#>   study_id first_name last_name    sex              ethnicity
#> 1     1001       John       Doe   Male     Hispanic or Latino
#> 2     1002       Jane     Smith Female NOT Hispanic or Latino
#> 3     1003       Jack     Jones   Male     Hispanic or Latino
#> 4     1004       Jill   Windsor Female Unknown / Not Reported
```

Answer (score 0):

I showed an example where the input data might be numeric, or character

```
(numframe <- data.frame(
  sex = 0:1
))

(charframe <- data.frame(
  sex = c("0", "1")
))

(instructframe <- data.frame(
  forvar = "sex",
  instruct = "0, Female | 1, Male"
))

library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
library(rlang)

options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE) # for base::dQuote()

instructframe2 <- tibble(instructframe) |>
  mutate(mycase_prep = list(map(stringr::str_split_1(
    string = instruct,
    pattern = fixed("|")
  ) |> trimws(), \(x)    stringr::str_split_1(
    string = x,
    pattern = fixed(",")
  ) |> trimws() |> dQuote() ))
  ,
  mycase_prep_2 = paste0(map(flatten(mycase_prep),
                \(x)paste0(x,collapse='~')),collapse=",")
  ,
  mycase = glue("case_match({forvar},
                {mycase_prep_2}) |> as.factor()"))

(pcases <- map2(instructframe2$mycase,
               instructframe2$forvar,
              \(x,y){element <- rlang::parse_exprs(x)
                names(element) <- y
                element}))


ne <- new_environment(data=list(charframe = charframe,
                          numframe = numframe))
walk(pcases,\(x){
  ne$charframe <- mutate(ne$charframe,
                         !!!x)
  ne$numframe <- mutate_all(ne$numframe,as.character) |> 
    mutate(
                         !!!x)
})


#results 
ne$charframe
ne$numframe
```